# MARIADB yocto project : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using **yocto project SUMO branch ( yocto 2.5 )** to build embedded linux kernel image.

I want to use **MARIADB** into my image. For that I added this variable in **local.conf** file :

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " mariadb"
```

and I rebuild the image, I can find now this packages in my release :

*mariadb, mariadb-client, mariadb-server, mariadb-setupdb ,libmysqlclient18 ...*

But when I reboot my kernel, and before making the login, I can see that error while booting :

```
Starting to install database for mariadb
done.
Starting MySQL..200820 12:07:09 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.err'.
200820 12:07:09 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '/var/log/mysqld.err' (Errcode: 13)
. ERROR!
```

Besides, when I try to start the server using mysql command under */usr/bin/* , an error occurs :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Help me please, how can I start the server and use mariadb ?

Comment: permissions issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /lib/systemd/system
systemctl start mysqld.service
```

This will work

Comment: The question clearly shows an error while attempting to start the service, this will do nothing to help.

Comment: In my case, the issue was the same. and I resolved it by hitting those commands. it should work. you can try once.